# Receiving An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected w/ActionCable checking for Null Users

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I'm trying to stop ActionCable from continuously checking for users that are not logged into the server. I deleted all users in my test environment to check if this issue would persist, but it shows no sign of ending, even after I added a conditional statement to the JS file to check for the current_user's id. How can I finally bring an end to ActionCable attempting to connect users that don't exist or aren't logged in? Btw, I'm using JQuery3 and Rails 5.

Console Log

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-27 00:11:41 -0500
   (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-27 00:11:42 -0500
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-27 00:11:42 -0500
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-27 00:11:42 -0500
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-27 00:12:09 -0500
```

connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.username
    end

    protected
    def find_verified_user
      verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
      if verified_user && cookies.signed['user.expires_at'] > Time.now
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

cable.js

```
// Action Cable provides the framework to deal with WebSockets in Rails.
// You can generate new channels where WebSocket features live using the `rails generate channel` command.
//
//= require action_cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./channels

(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);
```

chatroom.js

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
    if ($("meta[name='current-user']").length > 0) {
        (function () {
            App.chatrooms = App.cable.subscriptions.create("ChatroomsChannel", {
                connected: function () {
                },
                disconnected: function () {
                },
                received: function (data) {
                    var active_chatroom;
                    active_chatroom = $("[data-behavior='messages'][data-chatroom-id='" + data.chatroom_id + "']");
                    if (active_chatroom.length > 0) {
                        if (document.hidden) {
                            if ($(".strike").length === 0) {
                                active_chatroom.append("<div class='strike'><span>Unread Messages</span></div>");
                            }
                            if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
                                new Notification(data.username, {
                                    body: data.body
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            App.last_read.update(data.chatroom_id);
                        }
                        return active_chatroom.append("<div class='media message'> <div class='media-body'> <h5 class='mt-0 message-username-pos'>" + data.username + "</h5> <p>" + data.body + "</p></div></div>");
                    } else {
                        return $("[data-behavior='chatroom-link'][data-chatroom-id='" + data.chatroom_id + "']").css("font-weight", "bold");
                    }
                },
                send_message: function (chatroom_id, message) {
                    return this.perform("send_message", {
                        chatroom_id: chatroom_id,
                        body: message
                    });
                }
            });

        }).call(this);
    }
});
```

last_read.js

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
    if ($("meta[name='current-user']").length > 0) {
        (function () {
            App.last_read = App.cable.subscriptions.create("LastReadChannel", {
                connected: function () {
                },
                disconnected: function () {
                },
                received: function (data) {
                },
                update: function (chatroom_id) {
                    return this.perform("update", {
                        chatroom_id: chatroom_id
                    });
                }
            });

        }).call(this);
    }
});
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Test App</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/' %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= tag :meta, name: 'current-user', data: {id: current_user.id} %>
  <% end %>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

warden_hooks.rb

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = user.id
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = 30.minutes.from_now
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = nil
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = nil
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understood your question. However connection is initiated here:

```
(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);
```

So if you don't want to connect you could add the check here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I will post the solution, just for future references.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem of constant pinging by ActionCable, you must add a meta data checker inside of cable.js like below

```
    $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {
    if ($("meta[name='current-user']").length > 0) {
        App.chatrooms = App.cable.subscriptions.create("ChatroomsChannel", {
            ...
        });
    } else if(App.chatrooms) {
       App.chatrooms.unsubscribe();
       delete App.chatrooms; 
    }
});
```

Comment: just wondering: i see that part of this solution is in your chatroom.js file. did you remove the relevant code from that file and put it inside cable.js? and what is inside the `...`?